# Black Lines connected with doors

Tags: objects

I do not know how to get rid of these strange black lines in Blender. I tried several solutions but nothing solved the problem. These lines are connected with the doors. I got those doors from Archimesh. Can anyone please help me? Thank you a lot
[image]

Comment: it looks like children lines, are your object parented to an object?

Comment: How can I check it out?

Comment: select one of the objects, check in the Properties panel > Object > Relations, or check the Outliner, see if they are under another object. Maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I’m new here so I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: @moonboots How can I share my file? Thank you very much

Comment: use https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... upload your file, copy the URL it will generate and paste it here

Answer (score 0):

[image: Viewport Overlays]

In the Viewport Overlays panel, turn off **Relationship Lines**